# Improve Xubuntu Panel for grey background

Tags: xubuntu, customization, panel, xfce-panel

I have made a .png file with the background color of windows 98 taskbar and have set it as the background for xfce's panel.

However the text on the time as well as the bluetooth, wifi, and volume icons are white, and the panel's gray is too close to white, therefore the colors do not blend in.

How can I change the text to be black on a white background?

[image]

I am running Xubuntu 64 bit.

Comment: That's part of your GTK theme. See here for a suggested fix: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=8717

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved by following these steps:

1. run in terminal `touch ~/.gtk-2.0`
2. Run in terminal `leafpad ~/.gtk-2.0` (replace leafpad with your favorite text editor)
3. Paste this text into the text editor:

```
style "gtk-theme-config-panel" {
    bg[NORMAL] = "#000000"
    bg[PRELIGHT] = shade(1.1,"#000000")
    bg[ACTIVE] = shade(0.9,"#000000")
    bg[SELECTED] = shade(0.97,"#000000")
    fg[NORMAL] = "#729fcf"
    fg[PRELIGHT] = "#729fcf"
    fg[SELECTED] = "#729fcf"
    fg[ACTIVE] = "#729fcf"
}

widget "*PanelWidget*" style "gtk-theme-config-panel"
widget "*PanelApplet*" style "gtk-theme-config-panel"
widget "*fast-user-switch*" style "gtk-theme-config-panel"
widget "*CPUFreq*Applet*" style "gtk-theme-config-panel"
widget "*indicator-applet*" style "gtk-theme-config-panel"
class "PanelApp*" style "gtk-theme-config-panel"
class "PanelToplevel*" style "gtk-theme-config-panel"
widget_class "*PanelToplevel*" style "gtk-theme-config-panel"
widget_class "*notif*" style "gtk-theme-config-panel"
widget_class "*Notif*" style "gtk-theme-config-panel"
widget_class "*Tray*" style "gtk-theme-config-panel" 
widget_class "*tray*" style "gtk-theme-config-panel"
widget_class "*computertemp*" style "gtk-theme-config-panel"
widget_class "*Applet*Tomboy*" style "gtk-theme-config-panel"
widget_class "*Applet*Netstatus*" style "gtk-theme-config-panel"
widget "*gdm-user-switch-menubar*" style "gtk-theme-config-panel"
widget "*Xfce*Panel*" style "gtk-theme-config-panel"
class "*Xfce*Panel*" style "gtk-theme-config-panel"
style "panel"
{
    fg[NORMAL] = "#CED8EB"
}

widget_class "*Panel*"      style "panel"
widget "*Panel*"            style "panel"
class "*Panel*"             style "panel"
```

4. Reboot your computer.
5. For some reason, on my computer, It wouldn't work untill I logged out **AFTER** restarting and logged back in. You may need to do this too.

Comment: @ijustlovemath is this good?

Comment: No need to mkdir. You're writing a text file.

Comment: oops will fix thqt